# While using coroutines how do we map the domain model to a network entity?

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

According to the MVVM Architecture, the use of a data mapper class is mandatory as it maps the entity to the domain which can be used in the presentation layer. While using coroutines, do we explicitly need to create a Mapper Class.
For example this is the DataMapper class :

```
class PermissionDataMapper @Inject constructor() {

fun mapEntityToDomain(permissionEntity: PermissionEntity): PermissionDomain {
    return PermissionDomain(
        permissionName = permissionEntity.roleDesc,
        permissionId = permissionEntity.roleId
    )
}

fun mapEntityListToDomainList(permissionEntityList: List<PermissionEntity?>): List<PermissionDomain> {
    return permissionEntityList.map { permissionEntity ->
        mapEntityToDomain(permissionEntity!!)
    }
}}
```

Which is further used inside a DataRepositoryClass which maps the entity list to a domain list :

```
 override fun getSharePermissions(): Observable<List<PermissionDomain>> {
    return userDataSourceFactory.retrieveRemoteDataSource().getSharePermissions().map {
        return@map permissonsDataMapper.mapEntityListToDomainList(it)
    }
}
```

Do we need to follow this same pattern if we use coroutines? Or does the mapping of domain to entity or entity to domain happens in the background automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess yes,
It has to be done like this but shorter, the map function in coroutines just executes your mapping to each list item,

So in any case the actual mapping needs to be defined,

You know, the function doesn't know what to do with each developer element, there is no common similarities, you here mapped every element field to its corresponding one.